# Is there a delimiter/disambiguation syntax for submatch group references in JavaScript string replacement?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

This must have an answer somewhere already, but I don't even know what to search for.

In JavaScript, I can reference a parenthesized submatch in a replacement string like so:

```js
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".replace(/(.)/g, "$1-");
// Result: "a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-k-l-m-n-o-p-q-r-s-t-u-v-w-x-y-z-"
```

Now, I want to put a `1` instead of a `-` in between each letter:

```js
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".replace(/(.)/g, "$11");
// Result: "a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1i1j1k1l1m1n1o1p1q1r1s1t1u1v1w1x1y1z1"
```

At least Chromium seems to detect that there is no submatch group 11, so it interprets the replacement string as "submatch group 1 followed by a 1".

Let's assume there are 11 groups though:

```js
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$/, '$11');
// Result: "k"
```

What I would like to know:

- Will example 2 work cross browser? Is it defined somewhere that it should behave like this?
- Is there a way to explicitly delimit the submatch group reference? Something like in bash where `$a` and `${a}` refer to the same variable, but the latter makes it possible to delimit it from the following text. Something that would enable me to make example 3 output `"a1"` rather than "k".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript regex engine assumes the longest digit sequence after `$` is the group ID to refer to provided there is such a group in the pattern, so `$111` will refer to Group 111 if there is one in the pattern, or to Group 11 and `1` if there is Group 11, or to Group 1 and `11` if there are fewer than 11 groups. It will be returned as a literal string if there are no groups at all (i.e. `"x".replace(/./g, "$1")` returns `$1`).

```js
console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$/, '$11')); // => "k"
console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.).................$/, '$11')); // => "a1"
```

**You may *pad* the group ID with zeros** if you know there may be ambiguities in referring to groups in your pattern.

The `$011` will be disambiguated as backreference to Group 1 and `1`:

```js
console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$/, '$011')); // => "a1"
```

However, you may as well use [**named capturing groups with named backreferences**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges):

```js
console.log('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.replace(/^(?<name>.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)$/, '$<name>1')); // => "a1"
```

In the [*Table 54: Replacement Text Symbol Substitutions* table](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-replacement-text-symbol-substitutions), the backreference syntax is defined as either `$n` or `$nn`, however, even `$nnn` syntax is also allowed.

| Code units | Unicode Characters | Replacement text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0024, N Where 0x0031 ≤ N ≤ 0x0039 | `$n` where `n` is one of **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9** and `$n` is not followed by a decimal digit | The `n`th element of captures, where `n` is a single digit in the range `1` to `9`. If `n` ≤ `m` and the `n`th element of captures is **undefined**, use the empty String instead. If `n` > `m`, no replacement is done. |
| 0x0024, N, N Where 0x0030 ≤ N ≤ 0x0039 | `$nn` where `n` is one of **0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9** | The `nn`th element of captures, where `nn` is a two-digit decimal number in the range `01` to `99`. If `nn` ≤ `m` and the `nn`th element of captures is **undefined**, use the empty String instead. If `nn` is `00` or `nn` > `m`, no replacement is done. |